# Property does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an `events` table and a `tickets` table. I am trying to decrement the available tickets in `regular_atendies` by the ordered tickets and same for `vip`

This is my store method:

// Create Ticket

```
$ticket = new Ticket();
$ticket->userName = $request->input('userName');
$ticket->userEmail = $request->input('userEmail');
$ticket->phoneNumber = $request->input('phoneNumber');
$ticket->regular_quantity = $request->input('regular_quantity');
$ticket->vip_quantity = $request->input('vip_quantity');
$ticket->event_id = $request->route('id');
$ticket->total = $request->input('regular_quantity') + $request->input('vip_quantity');

$event = Event::find(1);
$event = Event::where('id',$ticket->event_id);

if ($ticket->regular_quantity<$event->regular_attendies) {
    DB::table('events')->decrement('regular_attendies', $ticket->regular_quantity);
} elseif ($ticket->vip_quantity<$event->$vip_attendies) {
    DB::table('events')->decrement('vip_attendies', $ticket->vip_quantity);  
} else {
    echo "error";
}

$ticket->save();

return redirect('/');
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You never execute your query. This line:

```
$event = Event::where('id',$ticket->event_id);
```

Needs a closure:

```
$event = Event::where('id',$ticket->event_id)->first();
// or ->firstOrFail();, etc
```

Otherwise, it's a `Builder` instance, and you can't access columns from a `Builder`. Using `->first()` will convert it to an `Event` instance, or `null`.

Also, having this:

```
$event = Event::find(1);
// ^ I assume this is used for testing, probably should comment it out.
$event = Event::where('id',$ticket->event_id)->first();
```

Is redundant. Use one or the other.

Comment: thanks i've used that and the error dissapeared but it does not follow the if statements because it still books even if it has exceeded the amount

Comment: Well, you don't have any code that prevents `$ticket->save()` from happening. If you hit the `else` block, you're just echoing "Error", but that doesn't stop execution. That's a separate issue though; if this code fixed your issue, please upvote and/or accept it, and consider asking a new question.